# Timezone from BeautifulSoup4 Webscrape is different from original source

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-calendar-api, timezone-offset

I'm using beautifulsoup4 to scrape info from a google calendar.  I generated a list containing the date, followed by the names of the people with an appointment, along with the time at which the meeting takes place.  For some reason, however, the time that is generated by the web scrape is 5 hours ahead, and I have no idea why.

Here is what I use to generate the list:

```html
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/htmlembed?src=stationhouston.com_rjtfsabha07jarsumdg7v95b10@group.calendar.google.com&amp&mode=AGENDA"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
soup2 = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"date-section"})
for item in soup2:
  print item.text
```

The original source displays times in CST, while the web scrape generates times in UTC.

Must the timezone be changed before I scrape the url?  Or is there a way to fix this using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Calendar isn't getting any timezone information, since you aren't using a browser. In lieu of a specific timezone, it will always default to UTC.

So, kind of a pain, but you could do it like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dateutil.parser import parse


def convert_time(x):
    from_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
    to_zone = tz.gettz('America/New_York')
    utc = x.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
    central = x.astimezone(to_zone)
    return central 

url = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/htmlembed?src=stationhouston.com_rjtfsabha07jarsumdg7v95b10@group.calendar.google.com&amp&mode=AGENDA"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
soup2 = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"date-section"})
for item in soup2:
    try:
        time_str = re.search('[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]', item.text).group(0)
        print("Old time was: {}".format(time_str))
        time_parsed = parse(time_str)
        res = convert_time(time_parsed)
        new_time = '{}:{}'.format(res.hour, res.minute)
        print("New time is: {}".format(new_time))
    except:
        pass
```

Here we use a regular expression to extract the time from the string.

We can use the `datetime.parser` tool to automatically convert that string to a Python `datetime` object.

From there we use the `convert_time()` function we defined above to convert that UTC timestamp to a CST timestamp.

As you can see, the output seems correct:

```
Old time was: 2:30
New time is: 22:30
Old time was: 2:30
New time is: 22:30
Old time was: 6:30
New time is: 2:30
Old time was: 3:30
New time is: 23:30
Old time was: 4:30
New time is: 0:30
Old time was: 7:30
```